# Error fotos con poca calidad Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy intentando hacer una foto desde mi telefono y mostrarla en un ImageView. Sigo los pasos de la web de Android Studio en la que indica como hacer una foto y mostrarla pero al mostrarla en el ImageView sale con muy poca calidad. No entiendo donde puedo estar fallando

Os dejo el codigo:

```
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cameraIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        }
    });
```

---

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap); // photo with low quality                
        }
    }
}
```

Y las variables y constantes;

```
private Intent cameraIntent;

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private Bitmap imageBitmap;
ImageView imageView;
```

Comment: Seguro que el dispositivo captura imagenes de buena calidad?

Comment: Si, he probado otras formas de hacerlo y las captura con buena calidad

Comment: @CMorillo revisa esta respuesta, tiene un ejempo completo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158478/imagen-pixelada-al-sacar-foto-android/158537#158537

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa, es que el intent te trae el `thumbnail`. Esto con el fin que uses esa imagen para desplegar en tu interfaz como icono o previo. Si quieres que la camara guarde tu imagen y tener acceso a la imagen de calidad completa, debes mandarle un `File` a tu camara, y ahi es donde se guardara la imagen en tamaño completo.

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Crea el File
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error cuando se creo el archivo
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext().getApplicationContext(),"com.tuapp.example" ,
                        photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
```

Y en el metodo `createImageFile`, crear el `File` que se manda en el `Intent` y guardas la ruta de la imagen completa.

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );  

    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.d(TAG,"el path de la imagen es = " + mCurrentPhotoPath);
    return image;
}
```

Por ultimo, en tu `manifest` es necesario que agregues un `provider`

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.tuapp.example"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

Despues de todas esas vueltas, en tu `onActivityResult`, despues de validar que el intent termino de manera correcta, puedes utilizar la imagen creando un `File` con la ruta completa del archivo.

```
File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
if(file.exists()){
    //tu archivo existe, haz lo que necesites
```

En la documentacion esta la seccion [Save the full-size photo](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath). Parte del código y una explicacion de como guardar la imagen la puedes encontrar ahi.

Comment: El problema es que este codigo me guarda la foto directamente y yo lo que quiero es primero visualizarla y luego guardarla o repetir la foto