# Imagen pixelada al sacar foto Android

Tags: android

Tengo una aplicación en la que hago uso de la cámara, el problema es que al sacar la foto, en la propia previsualización de la aplicación cámara de Android me aparece la imagen pixelada, aquí un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Accedo a la cámara de este modo:

```
val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_PICTURE)
```

Como digo es en la propia aplicación de la cámara donde se pixela la imagen, no en mi aplicación, donde posteriormente recibo la imagen también de esta forma.

Comment: Vea si esta solución le funciona: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10382217/8933039

Comment: Yo respondi una pregunta similar, revisa este [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150539/error-fotos-con-poca-calidad-android/150591#150591)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema aquí es que si despliegas la imagen al momento de tomarla, se genera una imagen de baja calidad. **Cuando se usa la cámara para guardar imágenes, lo recomendable es guardarla en el disco y posteriormente puedes obtenerla desde el disco y se mostrará con buena calidad.**

Recuerda que para Android 6.0 debes requerir el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` manualmente, además de definirlo en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`

[Error en permiso de almacenamiento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151390/error-en-permiso-de-almacenamiento/151413#151413)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Agrego un ejemplo completo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PICTURE_RESULT = 122 ;
    private ContentValues values;
    private Uri imageUri;
    private Button myButton;
    private ImageView myImageView;
    private Bitmap thumbnail;

    String imageurl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            //Verifica permisos para Android 6.0+
            if(!checkExternalStoragePermission()){
                return;
            }
        }

        myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
        myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
            myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "MyPicture");
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Photo taken on " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                    imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);    
                }
            });

    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICTURE_RESULT:
                if (requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT)
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        try {
                            thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                            myImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                            //Obtiene la ruta donde se encuentra guardada la imagen.
                            imageurl = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
        }
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    private boolean checkExternalStoragePermission() {
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
        } else {
            Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: Eso es! Muchas gracias!!

Comment: @IbrahimHernándezJorge un placer ayudar, saludos!

Comment: @Jorgesys en caso de querer guardar un nombre ya por default de la imagen como podria asignarselo o en que linea