# Evitar pérdida de calidad imagen Android

Tags: java, android

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para recopilar imagenes las cuales pueden provenir de la galería o capturarla al momento para luego enviarlas a una base de datos. Y el problema es que cuando la imagen viene de la cámara esta baja mucho su calidad, al contrario de la galería que se sube full.

Galería:

```
if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri contentURI = data.getData();
            try {
                FixBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ShowSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(FixBitmap);
                UploadImageOnServerButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(SuccessActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

Cámara:

```
else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
        FixBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ShowSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(FixBitmap);
        UploadImageOnServerButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
```

Y luego la subo

```
public void UploadImageToServer(){



    FixBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);

    byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
     }
```

Solucionado [Respuesta de Elenasys♦](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/238742/117768)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que al tomar la imagen con la camara y obtener los bytes, esta información en realidad esta definida para crear un "thumbnail" o prevista,

```
  ... 
  ...
   else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
        FixBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ShowSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(FixBitmap);
        UploadImageOnServerButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }   
   ...
   ...
```

por lo tanto cuando tratas de usar esta imagen en realidad se ve borrosa.

Para evitar perdida en la calidad de imagen, **la opción aquí es usar la imagen que almacenas en disco.**

```
 FixBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
```

Te sugiero revisar:

[Imagen pixelada al sacar foto Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158478/imagen-pixelada-al-sacar-foto-android/158537#158537)

Comment: Lo intenté pero al momento de ejecutar la parte de subir la app se cierra .

Comment: @QwertyUiop y funcionaba esa parte o no la habías probado, lo que comentaba en mi respuesta es que no la imagen que se obtiene con la camara mediante data es la que no debes usar porque en realidad es un thumbnail.

Comment: Funcionaba pero como dices Yo subo una miniatura por lo que intenté seguir tu explicación pero no .

Comment: ♦ Tengo una función para guardar la imagen pero también la guarda en forma de miniatura. Ya tengo rato en esta parte y necesito avanzar :L

Comment: Después de un rato ya está, muchas gracias.

Comment: Excelente saludos!