# Subir Imagen a servidor desde aplicacion Android sin perder calidad

Tags: php, android-studio, android-imageview

Estoy intentando subir una imagen a mi servidor que se toma desde la cámara de mi celular, estuve investigando de como hacerlo y encontré que es posible al convertir en base64, la cuestión es que al convertirla en base64 el tamaño de la imagen disminuye drásticamente y no es posible distinguir ni las letras

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para subirla al servidor utilizo el siguiente código:

```
private String convertImage(Bitmap image) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm = Bitmap
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);//imagen codificada

    return encodedImage;
}
```

Despues de codificar la imagen genero un JSON y en el mando la imagen y otra información al servidor por post con retrofit2:

```
 private void callBack(){
    alertDialogProgress();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ApiInterface.URL_BASE)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    String picture = convertImage(saveImage);
    String descriptionIncidence = textDescription.getText().toString();
    String idEmployee = "1";//Valor obtenido de archivo de preferencias

    ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("idEmployee", idEmployee);
        jsonObject.put("descriptionIncidence", descriptionIncidence);
        jsonObject.put("picture", picture);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String json = jsonObject.toString();

    Call<DoneObject> userCall = apiInterface.createIncidence(json);
    userCall.enqueue(new Callback<DoneObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DoneObject> call, Response<DoneObject> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                DoneObject doneObject = response.body();
                Toast.makeText(NewIncidenceActivity.this, doneObject.getDone(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                alertProgress.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<DoneObject> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("ret2", t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(NewIncidenceActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alertProgress.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

En mi servidor obtengo los datos, la imagen la decodifico y la guardo en un directorio.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
// header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
require 'mysql_connect.php';

$parametro = $_POST["json"];
$json = json_decode($parametro, true);

$picture = $json["picture"];
$descriptionIncidence = $json["descriptionIncidence"];
$idEmployee = $json["idEmployee"];

$date = date("Ymd");
$time = date("His");

$namePicture = 'img_'.$date.'_'.$time.'_'.$idEmployee.'.jpg';
$dirPicture = '../img-incidence/'.$namePicture;

$urlPicture = 'http://localhost/img-incidence/'.$namePicture;
// $urlPicture = 'http://localhost/pp/img-incidences/'.$namePicture;

$imgdecode = base64_decode($picture);
file_put_contents($dirPicture, $imgdecode );

$connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
if (!$connection) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{
    $query = "INSERT INTO incidencia (FECHA, HORA, DESCRIPCION, IMAGEN, EMPLEADO) 
    VALUES ('$date', '$time', '$descriptionIncidence', '$urlPicture', '$idEmployee')";

    if ($connection->query($query) === TRUE) {
        print (json_encode(
            array(
                'done' => 'done'
            )
            ));
    } else {
        print (json_encode(
            array(
                'done' => $connection->error
            )
            ));
    } 
    mysqli_close($connection);  
}
```

}
    ?>

Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda o consejo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues no creo que sea del todo el problema con Base64. Lo digo porque estoy haciendo una aplicación parecida usando imágenes de Galería y/o Cámara. Pero el problema que indicas me pasa solo cuando uso cámara porque si uso galería esta se convierte en Base64 pero llega al servidor con full calidad.
**Así se ve desde app:**
[image: Así se ve desde app]
**Y así es el resultado:**
[image: Resultado]

Comment: Si, es mi problema, cuando llegan al servidor llegan de un tamaño similar a la foto que subiste, he buscado desde ya hace unos días y no encuentro solución

Comment: @Albertozt Revisa esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158478/imagen-pixelada-al-sacar-foto-android/158537#158537

Comment: Asi es esa fue la solución, gracias por el aporte de la pregunta **Qwerty Uiop**