# no se esta viendo imagen previa a guardar los datos

Tags: java, android

Tengo una actividad donde tengo dos botones: subir imagen y tomar foto
Al presionar subir imagen se abre la galería de mi dispositivo y al seleccionarla se muestra una previa en mi imageview pero el boton tomar foto ejecuta la camara del dispositivo pero cuando la selecciono y al presionar aceptar no se muestra la imagen previa ni se guarda la imagen y tampoco tengo error en mi logcat:

Este es el metodo onActivityResult():

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==PHOTO_CONST && resultCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(absolutePath);
            img.setImageURI(uri);

            //Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo subir la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{

            if (data != null) {
                imgUri = data.getData();
                img.setImageURI(imgUri);
                imgURI = imgUri;
                Glide.with(this).load(imgUri).into(img);

                Toast.makeText(this, "Se subió la imagen ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo subir la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

Aqui cree la ruta donde se almacena la imagen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <external-path
        name="mImages"
        path="Android/data/com.example.ftsapp/files/pictures"/>
</paths>
```

Aqui el metodo tomarFoto();

```
public void tomarFoto(){
        Intent tomarFotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (tomarFotoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
            File photoFile = null;
            try{
                photoFile = crearFotoFile();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (photoFile!=null){
                Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),"com.example.ftsapp",photoFile);
                tomarFotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
                startActivityForResult(tomarFotoIntent, PHOTO_CONST);
            }
        }
        startActivity(tomarFotoIntent);

    }
```

También el método para crear el archivo de la foto;

```
private File crearFotoFile() throws IOException {
        String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "imagen "+timestamp;
        File storageFile = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File photoFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,
                ".jpg",
                storageFile
        );
        absolutePath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return photoFile;
    }
```

No esta devolviendo la imagen ni ningún dato.

Edicion:
Ahora estoy obtenido este error en mi Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ftsapp, PID: 1253
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:605)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:579)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
        at com.example.ftsapp.MainActivity8.tomarFoto(MainActivity8.java:229)
        at com.example.ftsapp.MainActivity8.onClick(MainActivity8.java:131)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7140)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7117)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27351)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Esto luego de cambiar mi metodo crearFotoFile por createImageFile():

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "Backup_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

Anexo Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_panoramica_pv_02"
        android:label="@string/app_name_long"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_pv"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ListaAct"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity3" />
        <activity android:name=".ListaGastos" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity9" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity8"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity7"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity6"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity5"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity4"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme_FTS" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme_FTS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
            <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.ftsapp"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
            </meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Aquí hay un ejemplo para cargar la imagen de previsualización: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158478/imagen-pixelada-al-sacar-foto-android