# Tengo un código que sube fotos a un servidor, pero al momento de subir una foto tomada con la cámara pierde mucha calidad

Tags: php, javascript, android, bitmap, upload

Estoy tratando de subir una foto a mi server y datos en mi base de datos, ya funciona esa parte con un php, y la foto sí se guarda en mi server, el problema es que cuando trato de subir una foto tomada con la cámara, puedo hacerlo pero se ve borrosa pierde mucha calidad, y al tomar una foto de la galería sí se sube con buena calidad, estoy interesado en la toma de cámara, por eso me interesa arreglar esto, es mi primera vez usando bitmaps y todo esto en android studio.

Mi código se ve así:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button GetImageFromGalleryButton, UploadImageOnServerButton;
ImageView ShowSelectedImage;
EditText imageName;
Bitmap FixBitmap;
String ImageTag = "image_tag" ;
String ImageName = "image_data" ;
ProgressDialog progressDialog ;
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream ;
byte[] byteArray ;
String ConvertImage ;
String GetImageNameFromEditText;
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection ;
URL url;
OutputStream outputStream;
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter ;
int RC ;
BufferedReader bufferedReader ;
StringBuilder stringBuilder;
boolean check = true;
private int GALLERY = 1, CAMERA = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GetImageFromGalleryButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonSelect);
    UploadImageOnServerButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
    ShowSelectedImage = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageName=findViewById(R.id.imageName);
    byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GetImageFromGalleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showPictureDialog();
        }
    });

    UploadImageOnServerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            GetImageNameFromEditText = imageName.getText().toString();
            UploadImageToServer();
        }
    });

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    5);
        }
    }
}

private void showPictureDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    pictureDialog.setTitle("Seleccione la subida:");
    String[] pictureDialogItems = {"Galería", "Cámara" };
    pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            choosePhotoFromGallery();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            takePhotoFromCamera();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
    pictureDialog.show();
}
public void choosePhotoFromGallery() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
}

private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri contentURI = data.getData();
            try {
                FixBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                //String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ShowSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(FixBitmap);
                UploadImageOnServerButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
        FixBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ShowSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(FixBitmap);
        UploadImageOnServerButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}


public void UploadImageToServer(){
    FixBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    class AsyncTaskUploadClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Image is Uploading","Please Wait",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String string1) {
            super.onPostExecute(string1);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,string1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ImageProcessClass imageProcessClass = new ImageProcessClass();
            HashMap<String,String> HashMapParams = new HashMap<>();
            HashMapParams.put(ImageTag, GetImageNameFromEditText);
            HashMapParams.put(ImageName, ConvertImage);
            String FinalData = imageProcessClass.ImageHttpRequest("http://10.213.71.188/waspruebaconexion/CaptureImg.php", HashMapParams);
            return FinalData;
        }
    }
    AsyncTaskUploadClass AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ = new AsyncTaskUploadClass();
    AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ.execute();
}

public class ImageProcessClass{

    String ImageHttpRequest(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> PData) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(20000);
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            bufferedWriter.write(bufferedWriterDataFN(PData));
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            RC = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (RC == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String RC2;
                while ((RC2 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    stringBuilder.append(RC2);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private String bufferedWriterDataFN(HashMap<String, String> HashMapParams) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> KEY : HashMapParams.entrySet()) {
            if (check) {
                check = false;
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append("&");
            }
            stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            stringBuilder.append("=");
            stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 5) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No se puede utilizar la cámara por favor otorgue el permiso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

He visto preguntas similares pero no me ha funcionado haciendo lo que dicen, creo que tiene algo que ver con el bitmap, o no sé si existe alguna manera mas fácil de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics) de Camera `data.getExtras().get("data")` retorna una vista previa de la imagen que se tomó, si necesitas la imagen en tamaño real debes proporcionar la ruta donde vas a almacenar la imagen para luego acceder a ella.

Para proporcionar la ruta cambia el metodo takePhotoFromCamera por:

```
private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, {uri de la foto})
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
}
```

para luego en el onActivityResult, acceder a la imagen de tamaño real mediante la URI.

Comment: Hola gracias por contestar, no entiendo la parte del Uri

Comment: @LuisErnestoSotoValleChang Revisa : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158478/imagen-pixelada-al-sacar-foto-android/158537#158537