# Guardar imagen android camera y utilizarla ( NO thumbnail )

Tags: android, archivo, android-imageview

Estuve buscando el problema que estoy teniendo, o la forma de realizarlo y no la encuentro. Necesito tomar una imagen con la camara en android ( use el ejemplo que da Google y pude logralo ) y guardarla en el celular ( tambien pude lograrlo ). La cuestion es que google te da dos ejemplos, el 1ro que tomes una foto y lo pongas en imageview pero con un thumbnail ( me salio ), y el 2do es tomar la imagen y guardarlo como archivo, yo quiero mostrar esa imagen guardada y no se como hacerlo.

Soy relativamente nuevo con android.

Gracias Q

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio te sugerimos revisar [ask], agrega lo que has tratado o investigado y modifica tu pregunta para evitar sea cerrada. Revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158478/imagen-pixelada-al-sacar-foto-android

Comment: Por favor no coloques solucionado am título de tu pregunta, con aceptar la respuesta alcanza

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Una opción es guardar la imagen en un fichero dentro de la propia aplicación y después recuperarla, para esto ya conoces la ruta, por lo que recuperarla es muy fácil:

```
File pictureFile = new  File("yourPath");

if(pictureFile.exists()){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
    ImageView pictureImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImageView);
    pictureImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```